# How can I parse this json file through php?

Tags: php, json

Im trying to parse this json file that has my store's products using php but with no luck! I'm new to php and I tried searching online but nothing had the answer. Here is part of my json file:

```
    [
  {
    "_type": "default",
    "description": [
      "Product Description comes here"
    ],
    "url": "here is the url to my seo friendly url",
    "price": [
      "11.64"
    ],
    "sizes": [
      "sizes come here"
    ],
    "images": [
      "image name and address is here"
    ],
    "_template": "5c1333451e128f546e451197f6c6061b3a66d1ee",
    "_cached_page_id": "5119b553b1512ae1a19d6cd0d3f29e51e111a90c",
    "name": [
      "product name is here"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_type": "default",
    "description": [
      "Product #2 Description comes here"
    ],
    "url": "here is the url to my seo friendly url",
    "price": [
      "11.64"
    ],
    "sizes": [
      "sizes come here"
    ],
    "images": [
      "image name and address is here"
    ],
    "_template": "5c1333451e128f546e451197f6c6061b3a66d1ee",
    "_cached_page_id": "5119b553b1512ae1a19d6cd0d3f29e51e111a90c",
    "name": [
      "product #2 name is here"
    ]
  }
]
```

This is just a sample of the whole json file but it follows this format. I tried writing the following php code to index it but as I said, no luck:

```
    <?php
// this code reads from the files provided to it and populates the     database with products

$jsondata = file_get_contents("55products.json");
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);


foreach ($json["products"] as $product)
{
    // now lets split it into smaller pieces
    foreach ($product as $product_infos) {
        print_r($product_infos);
        echo "<br /><br /><br />";


    }

}
```

But still can't access the contents or to be specific, I don't know how to access the data store in there. I understand this might be a very stupid question but all the tutorials online don't have a similar syntax so please help me out. 
Best regards.

Comment: The json you've posted looks to be properly formatted (I tried it through `json_encode` myself and it's fine.) Are you asking how to access the data inside? You're having the `json_encode` return the data as arrays rather than as `stdClass Object`s, so all you should need to do is `$product_infos[<array_key>]`

Comment: @ChrisSprague Thanks yes my issue was getting the inner arrays data which i really didn't know how to obtain! The guy who extracted my old websites data gave me the json file and left so I didn't know how to obtain the information. I appreciate your help and the fact that you took the time to reply to my question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner elements are arrays themselves, you'll need to access the values using the index 0

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
// var_dump($obj);exit;

foreach ($obj as $product)
{
    print $product["description"][0] . "<br/>";
    print $product["images"][0] . "<br/>";
    print $product["url"] . "<br/>";
    print $product["name"][0] . "<br/>";
}
```

Will ouput

```
Product Description comes here
image name and address is here
here is the url to my seo friendly url
product name is here
Product #2 Description comes here
image name and address is here
here is the url to my seo friendly url
product #2 name is here
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alex! It works!!!!!!!!!!! I appreciate your help like big time!

Comment: If the elements contained within each top-level array were more consistent, you could also make it a bit simpler by doing `foreach ($product as $key => $value) { print "$key: $value<br/>"; }` inside the existing `for`... though it wouldn't work exactly here since there are more nested arrays inside.